# How can I access the iphone / ipod clipboard using python?

Tags: iphone, python, clipboard, ipod-touch

I want to modify a python application written for the ipod/iphone.
It should copy a string into the clipboard so that I can use it in another application.
Is it possible to access the iphone clipboard using python?
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Thanks for replying.

A bit of background: The python program is a vocabulary program running locally on my ipod.
Often I want to look up the vocabulary in a dictionary.
Then I always have to repeat the following steps:

1. Select and copy the word.
2. Close the vocabulary program.
3. Open the dictionary.
4. Paste the word into the text field.
5. Press search.

I want to automate the process, therefore I want the python program to copy the word into the clipboard automatically and start the dictionary.
I figured out the part with the starting already, using URL schemes.
I was hoping to be able to automate the copying as well.

Comment: Since there is no standard Python environment for the phone I assume you are using some preassembled 3rd party framework that includes a python interpreter and some sort of Cocoa bridge. In order to get any sort of answers you probably need to be more specific about what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry no, I'm assuming since you mention python that this is a web-based application?  If so there is no way you can put something into/take something out of the user's clipboard automatically.  However if it is webbased the user will be able to select any text/image and copy to paste elsewhere.